# Datatables: Change row colour on image click using JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using JQuery when I click an img in a row, is it possible to change the background colour of the selected row?

Thanks

**Update**

```
$('.myLink').click(function() {
    $("#User tbody tr").on('click', function (event) {
           $("#User tbody tr").removeClass('highlightRow');
           (this).addClass('highlightRow');
    });
    $.ajax({
           ...
    });
});
```

This allows me to add the class when the row is clicked. I want to add the class on the row only when the image is clicked.

```
<table id="User" style="width: 100%;">
      <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>View Information</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           @foreach (var userinfo in Model)
           {
                 <tr>         
                     <td>
                         <img src="/Images/SilkIcons/information.png" alt="Click for more details" class="myLink" title="@userinfo.userID"/>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
           }
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well?

Comment: yes it is in fact possible! :) cant help more than that without any code!

Comment: use this code to `img` click event for selected row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updated:

```
$("#User tbody tr td img").on('click', function (event) {
       $("#User tbody tr").removeClass('highlightRow');
       (this).parent("td").parent("tr").addClass('highlightRow');
});
```

Comment: @user3849707 what is your html layout?

Comment: Im using razor and models.

Comment: I have a generic layout and this table is in a seperate cshtml file.

Comment: Ill give this a try one sec

Answer (score 0):

User the following selector try adding img after tr

```
   $("#User tbody tr >img").on('click', function (event) {
       $("#User tbody tr").removeClass('highlightRow');
       (this).addClass('highlightRow');
});
```

Or

```
  $("yourImage").on('click', function (event) {
       $(this).parent("tr").addClass('highlightRow');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question am assuming that you are using the datatables jquery plugin. If you are not using a plugin it may be worth looking into it to make your life easier.

The following page should answer your question [data tables highlights](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/highlight.html)

The code will look something like the following

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var table = $('#User').DataTable();

$('#User tbody')
   .on('click', 'img.myLink', function () {
      var tablecell= $(this).parent("td")
      var rowIdx = table.cell(tablecell).index().row;

      $(table.row(rowIdx).nodes()).addClass('highlight');

   })
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  $("img.myLink").on('click', function (event) {

       $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").addClass('highlightRow');
});
```

Comment: Okay will give it a try

Comment: try live method instead of on